# Eulerian Polynomial Generating Function Proof

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs, eulerian-numbers

The generating function for the Eulerian polynomials is

$$\frac{t-1}{t-e^{(t-1)x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}$$
where $A_n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ Euler polynomial and 
$$A_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n e_{nk}t^k $$.

Question: how can I prove that the below equality is also true?

$$(*)\ \ \ \ \  \frac{1-t}{1-te^{(1-t)x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}$$

Comment: What inequality?  That's an equality.  It is often taken as the definition of the Eulerian polynomials, in which case there's nothing to prove.  If not, how are you defining them?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The generating function was actually not given in my textbook, only $A_n(x)$ was given. I also had a typo in the equality that I want to prove.

Comment: @RobertIsrael any thoughts? :)

Comment: So what definition are you using?

Comment: @RobertIsrael  The only definition I'm given is $A_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n e_{nk}t^k $

Comment: That's not a definition, unless you know something else about $e_{nk}$.  Assuming you meant $x^k$ rather than $t^k$ (which wouldn't make any sense), it just says $A_n$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Comment: Multiplying the first formula through by $-e^{(1-t)x}$, we get exactly $$\frac{(1-t)e^{(1-t)x}}{1-te^{(1-t)x}}$$.

Comment: These can't both be true, since e.g. for $t=0$ they yield different results ($\mathrm e^x$ at the top and $1$ at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

The Eulerian polynomials have been defined in more than one way in the past.

Some define $A_n(x)=\sum_{w\in\mathfrak{S}_n}x^{\mathrm{des}(w)}$ (see, for example, [Shareshian, Wachs](https://www.math.miami.edu/%7Ewachs/papers/eulerian.pdf)).

This gives the generating function as
$$\frac{t-1}{t-e^{(t-1)x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}.$$

Others (for example, Foata) define the Eulerian polynomial to be generated by the statistic $(1+\mathrm{des}(w))$ for all $n\geq 1$, i.e. $A_n(x)=\sum_{w\in\mathfrak{S}_n}x^{1+\mathrm{des}(w)}$.

This will have the generating function that you have described later.
$$\frac{1-t}{1-te^{(1-t)x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}$$
As noted by [Joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) and [Alexander Burstein](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/499816/alexander-burstein), these are not the same.

See this wonderful [this article](https://irma.math.unistra.fr/%7Efoata/paper/pub117EulerUlam.pdf) on the evolution of the Eulerian polynomial from Euler's time to the present by Foata.